# React Apollo Link - How to forward operation after a promise has resolved?

Tags: reactjs, react-apollo, apollo-client

So I figured out how to setup a middleware to handle my auth tokens, as well as getting new ones, if need be. The problem is that, there is an edge case here when, after the promise is resolved, the operation gets forwarded without the proper headers set, leading to another call that could potentially be unauthenticated. I feel the trick here is pretty straightforward, but I can't seem to figure it out. Is there a way to return the results from a promise back up to the enclosed function? I haven't found much luck regarding this, but perhaps there is another way. Here is the code for setting up my middleware and Apollo client:

```
const authLink = new ApolloLink((operation, forward) => {
  operation.setContext(({ headers = {} }) => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    const tokenExp = token ? decodeJWT(token).exp : null;
    const currentTime = Date.now() / 1000;

    if(token && tokenExp >= currentTime) {
      // Check if token is expired. If so, get a new one and THEN
      // move forward
      headers = { ...headers,authorization: token ? `Bearer ${token}` : "", };
      return { headers };
    } else {

    // TODO: This would be replaced with the token service that actually
    // takes an expired token and sends back a valid one
    return fetch('http://localhost:4000/topics', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          query: `mutation LOGIN_USER(
            $email: String
            $password: String!
          ) {
            login(email: $email, password: $password) {
              id
              token
            }
          }
        `,
          variables: {
            email: "test@test.com",
            password: "test"
          }
        }),
      }).then(response => {
        return response.json()
      })
      .then(({ data: { login: { token } }}) => {
        // Put updated token in storage
        localStorage.setItem('token', token);
        headers = { ...headers,authorization: token ? `Bearer ${token}` : "", };
        return { headers };
      });
    }
  });
  return forward(operation);
});


/**
 * Setup the URLs for each service
 */
const httpTopicsServiceLink = createHttpLink({
  uri: 'http://localhost:4000/topics',
});

/**
 * Create the client instance for each GraphQL server URL
 */
export const TopicsClient = new ApolloClient({
  link:authLink.concat(httpTopicsServiceLink),
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
});
```

Comment: If ```setContext``` is returning a Promise, couldn't you add a ```then``` statement to it and forward there?

Comment: how do you mean? I've tried adding a .then to the operation and I get errors telling me that `Cannot read property 'then`' of undefined :/

Answer (score 1):

To be able to add a promise for an ApolloLink you can add `fromPromise` and `toPromise`

```
import { ApolloLink, fromPromise, toPromise } from '@apollo/client';

const withToken = new ApolloLink((operation, forward) => {
  return fromPromise(
    fetch(...).then(({ token }) => {
      operation.setContext(({ headers }) => ({
        headers: {
          ...headers,
          authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        },
      }));
      return toPromise(forward(operation));
    }),
  );
});
```

`ApolloLink` expects an `Observable` which `fromPromise` will help convert the promise from your fetch to the correct type.

Answer (score 0):

You can return your own Promise that will resolve either with the headers or another Promise from your fetch request:

```
const authLink = new ApolloLink(async (operation, forward) => {
  return await operation.setContext(({ headers = {} }) => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    const tokenExp = token ? decodeJWT(token).exp : null;
    const currentTime = Date.now() / 1000;

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if(token && tokenExp >= currentTime) {
      // Check if token is expired. If so, get a new one and THEN
      // move forward
      headers = { ...headers,authorization: token ? `Bearer ${token}` : "", };
      resolve({ headers });
    } else {

    // TODO: This would be replaced with the token service that actually
    // takes an expired token and sends back a valid one
    resolve(fetch('http://localhost:4000/topics', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          query: `mutation LOGIN_USER(
            $email: String
            $password: String!
          ) {
            login(email: $email, password: $password) {
              id
              token
            }
          }
        `,
          variables: {
            email: "test@test.com",
            password: "test"
          }
        }),
      }).then(response => {
        return response.json()
      })
      .then(({ data: { login: { token } }}) => {
        // Put updated token in storage
        localStorage.setItem('token', token);
        headers = { ...headers,authorization: token ? `Bearer ${token}` : "", };
        return { headers };
      }));
    }
    });

  }).then(res => {
    return forward(operation);
  });
});
```

Can't test this so I may have missed something, but that should ensure the request is finished before forwarding.

Comment: thanks for the response, but unfortunately, I'm getting an error of `Cannot read property 'then' of undefined`. I had tried something similar where I wrapped the entire operation.setContext in a Promise. Though I think the function has to return an observable instead of simply calling `forward(operation)` hmmmmm

Comment: EDIT: I misunderstood.  Maybe if the ApolloLink callback could be async?  You could ```await``` setContext.

Comment: Updated my answer, it's worth a shot!

Comment: Thanks for the effort? I was messing around then tried your version and I'm getting `forward(...).subscribe is not a function` error haha. I was getting that same error with something else I was doing. I even tried wrapping the entire thing in `from` from `rxjs` with no success :P